# Request not goin to Api when build apk Flutter

Tags: api, flutter

Apk builds successfully but when I send a request from apk to API The request didn't send.

```
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.9:8000/data/symptoms/'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      'title': title,
      'values':values,
      'status': status,
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Hi There. In it's current state, this is hard to answer. Post more code regarding you issue. How are you calling your api ? Are you using any packages ? Have you tried to handle the error callback of your api to see what error is coming ?

Comment: Working fine in debug mode

Comment: Are you using the same device in debug mode and after you build apk ? or are you using your own device for apk and emulator for debug mode ?

Comment: I am using my device of Samsung when debug and build apk

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly happening since you are hitting a non secure `http` api.

Try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your `application` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- Add this line -->
</application>
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Try handing the error case for your api call and show error on screen using `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error)));`

Comment: When I build apk any of API didn't get called

Comment: That's not possible @Proud. There must be some error that is coming up. connect your device to your laptop and use `adb logcat` in a terminal to see the logs. There would be many logs but try to see logs when you are opening you app.